# Can I have my shell display settings follow me?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, terminal

I use a local VM to remote into multiple boxes throughout the day. My preferred shell display setting is:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
export PROMPT_DIRTRIM=6
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\033[01;32m\]\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

This is set in my `.bashrc`. Is there a way to make this follow me from host to host?

Caveat: I don't know which hosts I'll be accessing on any given day. So pre-configuring these on each host I ssh into isn't really an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

For sure. Either you replicate that to all the .bashrc of your account on the remote servers, or in the respective sshd_config of each server, you configure the AcceptEnv line to inherit TERM, PS1, and PROMPT_DIRTRIM.

So it would be (LANG and LC_* are already there on my configuration):

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_* TERM PS1 PROMPT_DIRTRIM
```

You also have to configure on your side in ssh_config SendEnv on the exactly same manner.

If modifying the remote side is not an option, you can pass them through ssh *as long as the remote side does not overwrite them*.

```
ssh -l user remote_server   -t  "PROMPT_DIRTRIM='test'; exec bash"
```

Comment: Sorry, I've added an edit to my question. Setting this up on each host isn't really an option for me. Thanks though :)

Comment: I took the comment in consideration now.

Comment: Cool, so is there a way to pass the settings automagically? Can I modify (or even alias) the stock `ssh` to include these?

Comment: -t has to come at the end. Maybe a script or some alias kung fu

Comment: ...or a function in alias. At the moment dining.

Comment: You don't need to include `TERM`. "TERM environment variable is always sent whenever the client requests a  pseudo-terminal as it is required by the protocol."

Comment: Indeed, I even had in the past problems with OS/X passing a funny TERM to my Linuxes. Well remembered @muru